# Merging two tree sets

Tags: scala, set

I am trying to get the union of two sets. The are basically binary trees (but *not* guaranteed to be balanced). This is the code:

```
class MyNonEmptySet extends MySet{

union(that: MyNonEmptySet): MySet = {
    ((left union right) union that) incl elem
  }

}

class MyEmptySet extends MySet{
    union(that: MyNonEmptySet): MySet = that    
}
```

For smaller data sets the union works fine but when the data is a but larger, union doesn't ever return. It just goes on. I want to understand what is going wrong. If it is not returning it should at least run out of memory (stack overflow exception), right? How can I rectify this?

**#EDIT1**

It works if I change the paranthesis in the implementation of `NonEmptySet`.

```
(left union (right union that)) incl elem
```

I don't understand why? Both should give out the same result right? Why does one method take forever (but does not go out of memory) and the other works instantly for the same data?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that a binary tree is a good data structure is that it is sorted so you can do fast searches in log n time.

Looks like you do not use a sorted binary tree.

Your second algorithm works but all the work is done by

```
incl elem
```

That is rather slow.

The first algorithm has a recursive step that is doing an union of itself, but it will never leave the recursive step.

There are great tree set algorithms in Scala, I would just use one of those.

The right way to merge binary trees is to use red-black trees, but that is non trivial:
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

Comment: "Your second algorithm works but all the work is done by
incl elem". Can you please elaborate on this point? And why doesn't the first algorithm not work for larger data sets? I just want to know these answers. Anyway, I will go through your link of the right way to merge binary trees.

Comment: I was trying to say that instead of having an effective recursive algorithm doing divide and conquer, all the work of the merge is going to be done by the include. This is not taking advantage of the data structure.